# How to validate Username and Password in WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

**Scenario**
I'm developing an API, the request header of the API will contain a Username and Password. We need to validate the username and password. We are using Keycloak IAM, but it's not configured with our wso2 EI setup.

**Question**
My exact question is what's the best practice in wso2 EI to validate a username and password against IAM in the In-Sequence flow? Should we use DBLookup mediator or use send mediator for calling the authentication API of IAM?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be directly connecting the IAM Server's DB. If you prefer to do the validation in the in-sequence, call the IAM Server's Authentication Endpoint using something like a `Call Mediator` to validate your credentials. You can develop a common `Sequence` to hold the Authentication logic and reuse it in different services.

Another option is to write a custom handler. You can read more about this from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Applying+Security+to+an+API).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a Handler to the Service, it will be responsible for authentication [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Applying+Security+to+an+API).

- Using a Basic Auth handler
- Using a custom basic auth handler Using
- Kerberos to secure the REST API
- Using an OAuth base security token
- Creating the custom handler Creating the API Getting the OAuth token
- Using a policy file to authenticate with a secured back-end service
  Transforming Basic Auth to WS-Security

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Applying+Security+to+an+API